# Can this Chromebook connect to a wireless network with WPA2-PSK security?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, wireless-router

From various readings over the years, I have the notion that WPA-PSK is considered not secure, and that WPA2-PSK should be used as the security option for wireless routers.

A Chromebook (manufactured in 2020, so relatively recent) that I need to work with has three security choices for connecting to a wifi-network:

- WEP
- PSK (WPA or RSN)
- EAP

I don't see "WPA2" in that list.
Does "WPA" imply both WPA and WPA2?
Or does "WPA" mean strictly "WPA" and not "WPA2"?

i.e. would this be the only choice I could make on my wifi router's security setting:

[image: WiFi Router's Security Options]

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There actually *is* WPA2 in the list – it's called "RSN". (This is the IEEE name for the security mode, while "WPA2" is the Wi-Fi Alliance marketing name.)

I don't think any Chromebooks *exist* that could only do WPA but not WPA2/RSN, given that the latter was standardized in 2004.

Comment: (It's a bit like 802.11ax vs Wi-Fi 6, or like H.265 vs HEVC.)

Answer (score 3):

Even if the Chromebook only does WPA (which I highly doubt: as far as I know all Chromebooks from the last 4-5 years can do WPA2) you can still use the bottom setting (WPA+WPA2) on the router.
That setting simply makes the router default to WPA2 and fall back to WPA if a client device doesn't support WPA2.